MongoDB - Finding the degree of separation of two users
As suggested in this post, I'm proposing here my question.
I have a MongoDB collections spots which has documents representing the friendship between two users
{
  "_id":  "64a337de4538a04610900f0c",
  "user1": "6468022102781d442b82afd7",
  "user2": "648c7b6b75231cd99e43d7ab",
  "areFriends": true
}

My goal is to write an aggregation which, given two user's IDs, returns the degree of separation of them.
To be clear, something like that:

1 = direct friends
2 = friends of friends
3+ ecc..

I came across the above example of $graphLookup, and now I am wondering how to implement something similar.
The difference between my case and the other post is that my documents have not a unidirectional relation (from-to) but a bidirectional (user1, user2); so, there is not guarantee about that the wanted user is stored as user1 or user2.
In other sections of my code, I solve this problem ordering the input ids or using conditions like this:
  $cond: {
              if: { $eq: ['$user1', userId] },
              then: '$user2',
              else: '$user1',
          },

However, I've understood that conditions are not supported as filed (like connectFromField) in $graphLookup
Is anyone have a clue on how to face this particular problem, it would be very appreciated. Thanks.
EDIT
this is a revised version of the aggregation pipeline proposed by Ray
      { $match: { user1: id1 } },
      {
        $graphLookup: {
          from: 'spots',
          startWith: '$user1',
          connectFromField: 'user2',
          connectToField: 'user1',
          as: 'friendshipsViewLookup',
          depthField: 'degree',
          maxDepth: 2,
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: '$friendshipsViewLookup',
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
        },
      },
      { $match: { 'friendshipsViewLookup.user2': id2 } },
      {
        $project: {
          user1: 1,
          user2: '$friendshipsViewLookup.user2',
          degree: {
            $add: ['$friendshipsViewLookup.degree', 1],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: { user1: '$user1', user2: '$user2' },
          minDegree: { $min: '$degree' },
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          user1: '$_id.user1',
          user2: '$_id.user2',
          degree: '$minDegree',
        },
      }


You can create an ad-hoc view to facilitate your search. When creating the view friendshipsView, you can limit the search scope(and thus improve the search performance) by setting filters like "areFriends": true. The most important point for creating the view is that we also "sort" the user1 and user2 field. We use $min and $max to make sure user1 is always the smaller one than user2. In this way, you can perform the $graphLookup normally.
db.createView("friendshipsView", "friendships", [
  {
    "$match": {
      "areFriends": true
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "user1": {
        "$min": [
          "$user1",
          "$user2"
        ]
      },
      "user2": {
        "$max": [
          "$user1",
          "$user2"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground to demonstrate creating the view
After the view is created, you just need to perform a $graphLookup like the SO answer you provided.
db.friendshipsView.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "user1": "A"
    }
  },
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "friendshipsView",
      "startWith": "$user1",
      "connectFromField": "user2",
      "connectToField": "user1",
      "as": "friendshipsViewLookup",
      "depthField": "degree"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$friendshipsViewLookup"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "friendshipsViewLookup.user2": "C"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      user1: 1,
      user2: "$friendshipsViewLookup.user2",
      degree: {
        "$add": [
          "$friendshipsViewLookup.degree",
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground to demonstrate querying the view

Note:
Since we are specifying the 2 input users for search when creating the view, if a new pair of users is inputted then we will need to update/recreate the view. You may consider a once-and-for-all "sorting" for the collection using an update with an aggregation pipeline like this. In this way, you do not need to create a new view every time.

EDIT:
Even if the collection is indexed, it may not benefit this aggregation pipeline since we are performing the aggregation on the view, which is computed ad-hoc. You can consider using on-demand materialized view, which actually stores our computed view on the database. The step is similar to how we created the view. We just add a $out/$merge at the end of the aggregation pipeline.

Depends on your usage, you may want to drop any existing friendshipsView collection.

db.friendshipsView.drop()


create the materialized view with $out

db.friendships.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "areFriends": true
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "user1": {
        "$min": [
          "$user1",
          "$user2"
        ]
      },
      "user2": {
        "$max": [
          "$user1",
          "$user2"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$out": {
      "coll": "friendshipsView"
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

index the view

db.friendshipsView.createIndex( {user1: 1, user2: 1 } )

Now, your view is ready for the query.
With your revised query, you can see that it is using IXSCAN in the indexed view.
partial explain output:
...
          "winningPlan": {
            "inputStage": {
              "inputStage": {
                "direction": "forward",
                "indexBounds": {
                  "user1": [
                    "[\"A\", \"A\"]"
                  ],
                  "user2": [
                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                  ]
                },
                "indexName": "ix",
                "indexVersion": 2,
                "isMultiKey": false,
                "isPartial": false,
                "isSparse": false,
                "isUnique": false,
                "keyPattern": {
                  "user1": 1,
                  "user2": 1
                },
                "multiKeyPaths": {
                  "user1": [],
                  "user2": []
                },
                "stage": "IXSCAN"
              },
              "stage": "FETCH"
            },
            "stage": "PROJECTION_DEFAULT",
            "transformBy": {
              "_id": 1,
              "friendshipsViewLookup.degree": 1,
              "friendshipsViewLookup.user2": 1,
              "user1": 1
            }
          }
...

Mongo Playground

Thank you so much for the beautiful answer! I didn't  know the view "trick", so nice to have. However, as you suggested, I had already the ids fields sorted. I think that your approach is missing the fact that we can have multiple paths to connect the users; so I added a final group aggregation to only output the minimum distance (you can see the pipeline in the EDIT). The problem is now performance, it takes TOO much (> 5 seconds), even if I limited  the depth to only 2. I didn't something wrong? (Of course the collection is indexed)

@NiccolòCaselli Thanks for the feedback first. I updated the answer to include an alternative that is a materialized view, which should be able to use an index. Also, I corrected a bug for incorrect pruning of nodes when creating the view.

Yes, thanks. I'm sure I explained myself badly, but as I was telling you, I don't think the view is a problem because I haven't used it; I preferred, as you suggested, to modify the entire collection and be careful when creating the fields, that they are sorted. Since there is the index and also the degree search depth is very low, it still seems very strange to me that the aggregation takes more than 5 seconds, a lot! So I was wondering if you had any advice? If not, it doesn't matter, I'll mark your answer as correct anyway because it works, even if I don't understand why it's so slow :)

@NiccolòCaselli We might need more details to take a deeper look. It could be a good idea to ask a new question with some sample json documents, the latest version of aggregation that you are using and also the explain plan
